# Why doesn't C++20 use `requires` to restrict the T for atomic<T>?

Tags: c++, atomic, c++20, c++-concepts

A generic `std::atomic<T>` is required to have a `T` that is *Copy Constructible* and *Copy Assignable*:

> **[[atomics.types.generic]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.types.generic#1)**
>
> The program is *ill-formed* if any of
>
> > (1.1) `is_­trivially_­copyable_­v<T>`,
> > (1.2) `is_­copy_­constructible_­v<T>`,
> > (1.3) `is_­move_­constructible_­v<T>`,
> > (1.4) `is_­copy_­assignable_­v<T>`,
> > or (1.5) `is_­move_­assignable_­v<T>`
>
> is `false`.

The above is not new to C++20. Compilers may use *`static_assert`* to issue an error for a non-conforming T.

However, C++20 could use formal *constraints* with the *`requires`* syntax to formally require the above as part of the type, e.g. something like:

```
template< class T > requires
    std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T> &&
    std::is_copy_constructible_v<T> &&
    std::is_move_constructible_v<T> &&
    std::is_copy_assignable_v<T> &&
    std::is_move_assignable_v<T>
struct atomic { ... };
```

---

**Is there a reason why C++20 refrained from using formal *constraints* for this purpose?**

---

**EDIT:** *@T.C.* points out correctly, in an answer below:

> For `std::atomic` in particular, constraining the primary template is
> simply not an option, given the `atomic<shared_ptr<T>>` and
> `atomic<weak_ptr<T>>` specializations that were added in C++20.

with an option suggesting that:

> Perhaps you can do something fancier (like an undefined and
> unconstrained primary template plus a constrained partial
> specialization), but it adds very little value.

Well, there is another option, without the need for *an undefined and
unconstrained primary template*, which is still a bit complex and reduces the value and fun in going with concepts for this usage, but probably better than an undefined base template:

```
template< class T > requires
    std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T> &&
    std::is_copy_constructible_v<T> &&
    std::is_move_constructible_v<T> &&
    std::is_copy_assignable_v<T> &&
    std::is_move_assignable_v<T>
    || std::same_as<T, std::shared_ptr<typename T::element_type>>
    || std::same_as<T, std::weak_ptr<typename T::element_type>>
struct atomic { ... };

template< class T >
struct atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>> { ... };

template< class T >
struct atomic<std::weak_ptr<T>> { ... };

// types of all other specializations are Copy Constructible and Copy Assignable
```

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/JaCu78

Comment: Most likely inertia. The C++ standard is vast, and it's next to impossible to recode everything in it to reflect the latest trend. As long as the specification is good and sound, why bother?

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica of course this is a reasonable thought. The question is whether there might be a side effect that worried the committee (e.g. breaking somehow old code that added its own specialization)?

Comment: Which is why I didn't post it as an answer. Only someone from within the standards committee could do that. I'm just a humble programmer with a hunch... :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The library specification deliberately avoids using any particular technology to achieve its goals [P0788](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0788r3.pdf):

> IV. Let’s avoid any specification that demands any particular technology by which implementations must comply with Library specifications.
>
> a) Let’s permit an implementation to use a *requires-clause*, an `enable_if`, a `constexpr if`, or
>   any other technology or combination of technologies to meet *Constraints:* specifications.
>
> b) Let’s permit an implementation to use `static_assert` and/or any other technologies to
>   meet *Mandates:* specifications.
>
> c) Let’s permit an implementation to use Contracts attributes [P0542R1] and/or any other
>   technologies to meet *Expects:* and *Ensures:* specifications.
>
> d) Let’s consider user code that relies on any specific technology on the part of an implementation to be ill-formed, with no diagnostic required.

Which is expanded upon in [P1369](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1369r0.pdf).

The goal is to avoid tying the *specification* of the library to any particular *implementation* of it. There are cases where you do need to do this - many of the Ranges things do require concepts to work, so they are specified in this way - but for the most part, you don't.

For the user, the important part is the mandated requirements on `T`. It's not important *how* those requirements are enforced. It could be a concept, it could be a `static_assert`, it could be some compiler intrisic, whatever.

Comment: Now, I'm no concepts expert, but isn't `static_assert` less friendly to other code using `atomic<T>` to test if `T` can be used to instantiate atomics?  Ie, there are observable differences to users.  And the standard uses different wording when, in effect, implementors are not allows to just `static_assert` or linker fail or whatever.  It seems plausible that this is what Amir actually cares about, even if Amir didn't actually ask about that, because it is a very pedantic difference.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont It is, yes, because you could check `requires { atomic<T>(); }`. But `static_assert` is more friendly for users. It's not a great story really. But the standard does specify the things to check if you want to just check them yourself.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Also that's not any different from what already exists with Constraints vs Mandates, and some of those are deliberate design choices as well (e.g. `tuple_element<I, T>` [mandates](http://eel.is/c++draft/tuple#helper-2) the size, it doesn't constrain it).

Comment: 'many of the Ranges things do require concepts to work' - how is it so? isn't it just duck typing? In what way is it different than mandating T to conform to a certain requirement and assume it does, without constraints?

Comment: @AmirKirsh For overloading purposes, a lot of the library needs concepts to work.

Comment: We can rewrite the ranges spec in non-concepts. It would just be ridiculously verbose and error-prone (capturing the fine details of partial ordering in an overload set in prose is less than simple) and serve no purpose whatsoever, especially since ranges is in part a POC for concepts.

Answer (score 3):

For `std::atomic` in particular, constraining the primary template is simply not an option, given the `atomic<shared_ptr<T>>` and `atomic<weak_ptr<T>>` specializations that were added in C++20.

Perhaps you can do something fancier (like an undefined and unconstrained primary template plus a constrained partial specialization), but it adds very little value.